# CorePlot: how to run on device? (works OK on simulator)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator, core-plot

My app uses CorePlot and runs fine on simulator
(it accesses libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a from:
         /Users/myName/core-plot/build/Debug-iphonesimulator ).

To run on device, xcode expects libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a in:
     /Users/myName/core-plot/build/Debug-iphoneos
but that file is missing, so xcode gives error:
    '/Users/Giovanni/core-plot/build/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a: No such file or directory'

I tried generating one by doing:
    CorePlot-CocoaTouch.proj > set Xcode to build on 'device' > 'Build And Run' 
but 'Build and Run' is grayed out.
Copying the simulator version obviously does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION: the issue was CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj must also be added as Targets>MyApp>getInfo>DIRECT dependency (in addition to as subproject and in addition to libCorePlot-CocoaTouch being added as Targets>MyApp>getInfo>LinkedLibraries). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj as a sub-project and then add libCorePlot-CocoaTouch as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks, but CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj is already a sub-project of the app and 
libCorePlot-CocoaTouch is already a dependency (in Targets>MyApp>getInfo>LinkedLibraries).
That is why it works in simulator.   

The error message indicates issue is missing file in /Users/myName/core-plot/build/Debug-iphoneos.
(but this file is present in /Debug-iphonesimulator so it works in simulator).

Comment: If you nuke the build directory and rebuild, what files does it output? I'm guessing that it outputs something called libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a but sticks it in the wrong directory. In general, I find that subprojects generally go wrong (it fails to set the right SDK if you build with xcodebuild).

Comment: No, enven after nuking myApp/build and doing myApp>BuildAndRun, that file does not build (in myApp/build). I guess it does not build because  it is linked as dependency. That file is only found in /Users/myName/core-plot/build/Debug-iphonesimulator (with old date of nov 7, so it does not build if running in simulator either).

Comment: SOLUTION: the issue was CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj must also be added    as Targets>MyApp>getInfo>DIRECT dependency (in addition to as subproject and in addition to libCorePlot-CocoaTouch being added as  Targets>MyApp>getInfo>LinkedLibraries). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the Core Plot project itself and building the framework first. You should build (not "Build and Run") the CorePlot-CocoaTouch target. Do it for each combination of SDK {simulator, device} and configuration {debug, release} (total of four builds). This will create the `.a` files you need.

After Core Plot is built, go back to your project and build it. It should now link and run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here if you don't want to use the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj import method (don't need to import the whole project, only the CorePlotHeader folder and the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a library file)  [Fix linker errors for Core Plot when using Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411077/ios-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5-possibly-core-plot-related/19524570#19524570)

Ultimately you might need to delete the old library by right clicking on your MyApp.app file in the Products folder and copy and past the new CorePlot_1.4 .a file into the Debug-iphoneos folder...clean, build, and it should run on an iOS 7 device.