# iOS - Core Plot Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios6, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS - Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5, possibly Core Plot related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411077/ios-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5-possibly-core-plot-related)

I have the problem described in this post:

[iOS - Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5, possibly Core Plot related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411077/ios-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5-possibly-core-plot-related)

However being pretty new to this i still do not understand how to solve this problem, recompile the library, and have to reach out for some help.

I have cleaned etc.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues could be at play here (iOS Deployment Target, ARMv7s Requirement). Let's start with making sure your Deployment target is at least set to 4.3 in the Summary tab of your Target.

Comment: Big thankyou for helping! : check, it is 5.0

Comment: If that worked, please mark my answer accordingly. If not, I may be able to address any ARMv7s issues if they are showing up in the logs.

Comment: Hi,check means that i have checked that. Does not work yet.