# iOS - Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5, Core Plot related?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS - Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5, possibly Core Plot related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411077/ios-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5-possibly-core-plot-related)

I have an IPhone  application which i am trying to convert to xcode 4.5.But linker error is coming .I have done all the things in this step, [iOS - Core Plot Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610294/ios-core-plot-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5)  and also in the link mentioned there.But not yet succeeded.can any body help me in achieving this?

Comment: please post the error on the console for better understanding

Comment: @Sharanya   file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice:  Rating/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) this is it.

Comment: Did you check this link ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411077/ios-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5-possibly-core-plot-related

Comment: Simply i compiled the core-plot library and followed the Dependent Project install from this link http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications  
and every thing going like a charm (my project now support both armv7 and armv7s without any problems) , in addition i still set Build Active Architecture Only to NO , to be sure to support all Architectures

Comment: inaddtion , change the compiler type for core-plot project (internal) to LLMV GCC 4.2  , and set the compiler time for your project (external) to Default compiler

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the default compiler to **LLMV GCC 4.2** in your Project build settings.It's strange but worked for me

Comment: @AppDelegatehow to change it?

Comment: Go to the Build Settings of your project/target, and look for the compiler selection setting. It is a drop-down menu and just select the  one you want.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @AppDelegate i changed but still the same error?