# How to rebuild a Third-Party library in Xcode 4.5 GM

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, core-plot, armv7

I'm trying to use a library called "CorePlot" in iOS application , ***everything was fine before upgrade Xcode to Xcode 4.5.1 to support ios6.***

After upgrade this error occurs

> file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice:
>   Lib/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a for architecture armv7s

Now after long search and depending on this link

[iOS - Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5, possibly Core Plot related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411077/ios-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5-possibly-core-plot-related)

the solution is to *rebuild the library* using the new Xcode 4.5GM

**But how to do rebuild process ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5, possibly Core Plot related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411077/ios-linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5-possibly-core-plot-related)

Comment: Simply i compiled the core-plot library and followed the Dependent Project install from this link http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications  
and every thing going like a charm (my project now support both armv7 and armv7s without any problems) , in addition i still set Build Active Architecture Only to NO , to be sure to support all Architectures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with one of my static libraries.  Basically, you will need to have the library recompiled to support armv7s, but in the meantime, you can remove that requirement from the build settings.

In your project settings, look for Architectures and I'm guessing it says, "Standard (armv7, armv7s)"  Remove it and replace with "armv7" and your project should compile.

Comment: but tell me please , when i remove "Standard (armv7, armv7s)" and replace with "armv7" , dose the app will be supported for iphone5 ?
what is the value of armv7s ? and when we remove it what are the effects on the app ?

Comment: armv7s is the architecture for the iPhone 5 so when you remove it, you won't be able to run it on an iPhone 5, but at least you'll be able to  compile your app.  To support the iPhone 5, you'll need to recompile that library to support armv7s.  Seeing as it is an open source project, you do have access to the source code.  Either create a new static library, or incorporate the source into your project.  If armv7s gives compile snafus, reach out to the Core Plot folks as they'll know how to handle.  Good luck!

Comment: Simply i compiled the core-plot library and followed the Dependent Project install from this link http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications  
and every thing going like a charm (my project now support both armv7 and armv7s without any problems) , in addition i still set Build Active Architecture Only to NO , to be sure to support all Architectures

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. What I did is in my project target, in the build settings, under the Build Active Architecture Only, change it to Yes.

Comment: thanks for replay ,i know this solution , but i think this is not optimal because we need the app to support all Architectures NOT only the current one , what do you see ?

Comment: Which way do you add core plot to your project? You know, there is two ways to do so. Dependent Project Install and Static Library Install. Using first way and Modify the "Valid Architecture" setting on the target to include armv7s and rebuild it. But if you want to save your time, just set build active architecture only Yes, but remember when distribute set it back to No.